# Generating a new route for a "public" link from a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a "public" link, which gives someone access to a particular page of my application without needing to be logged in/authorised.

I'm a little bit lost as to the best way to solve this, so looking for some advice.

To get started, I've added a `random_id` to the table of the object I'm building the link around (`Captable`).

What I'm now struggling with is: should I build a whole new controller (for example `PublicCaptableController`) and view for this public link so I can control what this "public viewer" will see? Or is there any easier way to create a new view using my existing CaptablesController that serves a selected set of information that I can control using the existing controller?

One idea I had was to edit my `application_controller.rb` with the following:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, unless: -> params[:random_id].present?
```

But this feels like a fairly big security risk. How could I do this in a simple, but more effective/secure way?

Thankful for any guidance/help!

**Here is my `routes.rb` file.**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  get '/landing', :to => redirect('/landing.html')
  root 'companies#index'
  post "companies/switch_current_company_context" => "companies#switch_current_company_context"

  resources :companies do
    resources :shareholders
    resources :captables do
      post :subscribe_to_captable
      resources :events do
        post :lock_event
        post :unlock_event
        resources :transactions
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**snippet from CaptablesController**

```
class CaptablesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_company
  before_action :set_captable, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @captables = @company.captables
  end

  def show
    @captable = Captable.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**Snippet from ApplicationController**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception, unless: -> { request.format.json? }
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    # Set a default current company scope for a use after signing in
    session[:current_company] = current_user.companies.first.id unless current_user.companies.empty?
    puts session[:current_company]
    companies_path

  end

end
```

Comment: What's in `CaptablesController`? How do you authorize a user to do something? how will you authorize a loggedout user using that `random_id`? Personally, I would use the same controller and links but with a query string with that random_id and on the authorization method I would check if there's a param for that random_id too.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Added some snippets from my captablescontroller + ApplicationController now. Basically I have a before_action in my application controller that checks the user is authorised. 

Your suggestion is pretty good I think that I just have a `?random_id=`in the query string and allow the page to be shown if the user is logged out BUT that random_id exists. I'd really only like to let a non authorised user view ONE specific view (captable#show) but I think I'd also prefer to use a separate template with far less information etc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update: This answer is outdated. In modern versions of rails you should use [`has_secure_token`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SecureToken/ClassMethods.html) instead of reinventing the wheel.

You could add a simple access token to the model and use it bypass authorization / authentication when passed through the query string.

First add the column to the table:

```
rails g migration add_access_token_to_captables access_token:string
rails g migrate
```

Then you want a suitible psuedorandom token string. The Ruby Stdlib has a SecureRandom module that has you covered.

```
SecureRandom.hex(10) #=> "52750b30ffbc7de3b362"
```

Lets setup a model callback to generate a random token on creation:

```
class Captable < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  after_validation :set_access_token!, if: :new_record?

  private


  def set_access_token!
    self.access_token = loop do
      random_token = SecureRandom.hex(10)
      break random_token unless self.class.exists?(access_token: random_token)
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can use the token to conditionally skip the callbacks:

```
class CaptablesController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user, if: :has_valid_access_token?, only: :show

  private
    def has_valid_access_token?
      params[:access_token].present? && Captable.exists?(params.permit(:access_token, :id))
    end
end
```

This is more secure than handling it in your ApplicationController since you are selectively adding a single exception.

This is a simpler approach that which uses a single token to give anybody access to a single resource. You could also create one time tokens by creating a seperate table and destroying / invalidating them after use.

Comment: Hmm when trying to create a new captable I got the following error:

`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: captables.token: SELECT 1 AS one FROM "captables" WHERE "captables"."token" IS NULL LIMIT ?`. This line throwing the error: 

`break random_token unless self.class.exists?(token: random_token)`

Comment: Sorry it should be access_token

Comment: Now I can access all the captable show views regardless of whether there is an access_token in the params or not - will continue to tweak the private controller method - can you see any issues in there? It doesn't seem like the has_valid_access_token method checks whether the access token relates to the captable the user is trying to view or not?

Comment: To clarify my question, now if I take any captable link and open it in an incognito browser - I can access the show view even though there is no `access_token` in the query string. I have a feeling something in the `has_valid_access_token?` needs tweaking.

Comment: Dig some digging - seemingly using conditionals in skip_before_action has been proven to cause some issues. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9703 Will try some other solutions to the skip. Otherwise your solution will work great! @max

Comment: Solved it by changing to a `before_action :authenticate_user!, unless: :has_valid_access_token?, only: [:show]`. For some reason the user can still access the edit method but I'll fix that somehow :)

Comment: Judging by the comments to that issue you should be able to fix it by using `return false unless action_name == "show"` inside the `has_valid_access_token?` method.